# CopyFile succeed, MoveFile fails with the same parameters - C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am dealing with a very frustrating problem in C++.
I need to use MoveFile function but this fails. Right now I am using CopyFile like this:

```
partialresult = L"D:\\CppWork\\test2\\decToBin.exe";
finala = L"D:\\CppWork\\test2\\PeFiles_\\decToBin.exe";

if (0 == CopyFile(partialresult, finala,b)) {/////
   DWORD err = GetLastError();
   std::cout << " -> Copy Fail" << std::endl;
}
```

Copy works ok but if I replace CopyFile with MoveFile (without changing the paths) fails with code 0x20 ([MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) ->**ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**).
Also if I try to replace MoveFile with CopyFile and then DeleteFile the file from the previews path, Copy works but Delete fails again with **ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**.

```
bool b = false;
if (0 == CopyFile(partialresult, finala,b)) {//copy works but when try to delete the file give error
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << " -> Copy Fail" << std::endl;
    outFile   << " -> Copy Fail" << std::endl;
 }
  else {
    std::cout << " -> Copy Done" << std::endl;
    outFile   << " -> Copy Done" << std::endl;
    if (!DeleteFile(partialresult))
        DWORD err= GetLastError(); //error is "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
  }
```

Has anyone some ideea what is happening here?
Thanks.

Comment: `net helpmsg 32` (=0x20) gives "_The process cannot access the file **because it is being used by another process**._" ... is the EXE in use? This would fail a move/delete but let a copy work fine.

Comment: I am so stupid...I haven't seen the value of the error code are in hex. That is right, the exe is in use. Is there a way to delete a file with the process in use?

Comment: IIRC (but might be wrong) there's a flag that says "mark it for deletion when it's no longer in use" (but I might be getting confused with how Unix works).

Comment: You can open a file using [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag, but the file has to be opened with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` by whoever is using it at that point

Comment: I have found some example on the internet with FILE_SHARE_DELETE but when the application finish (no error- finish normally) the file aren't deleted.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I have solved the problem like this  : **CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_DELETE,NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,NULL);**. Maybe help somebody. Thanks for repley.

Comment: @fhffhf Glad you found a solution. You should add that as an answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with CreateFile by marking them for delete after the process has finish like this:

```
 CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_DELETE,NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,NULL);
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: That sounds a bit more like a work-around. I would dig a little further.

Comment: do you have any more elegant idea? I am open to suggestions.:D

Comment: touche, I just meant look for those presumed failure to close handles.